# There is no salary accounts in my company but it companies asking bank statements

Tags: salary

I'm working with an IT company since one year. It has only six employees. We do not have salary accounts.

Now I am looking for change but IT companies are asking bank statements but I do not have one.
What should I do now?

Comment: 1. Tell them that you don't have a bank account? 2. Open a bank account?

Comment: How are you paid? Cash in an envelope?

Comment: Yes cash in envelope.

Comment: we need minimum 10 employees to open a bank account

Comment: Your question is not completely clear. Do you mean to say that the company does not have a bank account, and that your customers want you to have one? Also, what country are you in? What is your role in the company?

Comment: now im looking for job change. when i going interview they are asking last 3 months bank statements

Answer (score 4):

Tell them you don't have a salary bank account. They want bank statement because they want to verify your salary you can do this. Make a latter on the letterhead of your company and specify your salary in that. most companies accept it in case you don't have a bank account

Comment: am i eligible for tcs,wipro and infosys

Comment: yes offcource, if you have talent that company needs. than no one can reject you only for a bank recipt

Comment: I have worked for consultant company with two clients about an one year how can I include that in my CV